# How to use several bridges with docker?

Tags: networking, docker, bridge

I am testing docker as an alternative to `systemd-nspawn`. I would like to use one separate bridge per container.

All the documentation I saw is about either using `docker0` or creating an alternative bridge - to be used by all the containers (who share the same bridge).

**Is this something possible with docker?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible. Have a look here https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/networkingcontainers/

First you create new network

```
docker network create -d bridge my-bridge-network
```

And then when starting your container - you specify which network it should be attached to

```
docker run -d --network=my-bridge-network --name db training/postgres
```